# default viewer on Windows mobile 6.x

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

How can I find out if a default viewer exist for a file type (PDF for example)? I am planing to use `ShellExecute` to open a PDF file that I have downloaded from server, but I need to know if the device is capable of viewing the file before I attempt to download it.

P.S. This is a Visual C++ 2008 mobile project.

Thank You
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as with the desktop.  For example, for PDFs you'd look in the registry (with [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891460.aspx) and its relatives) for an extension association:

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf]`

If that exists, the default value will be the name of another key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, which you'd open to

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{class name}\Shell\Open\Command` which would tell you what, exactly, ShellExecute will run.

Comment: I knew about this method. I just wished there was a better way :o(

Comment: What's wrong with this method?  It's how all file associations are made.

Comment: I was hoping for something like an API that tells me what application are associated with a specific MIME type. Something like what android does.